# Failed to create agent because it is not close enough to the NavMesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

I have third party package which is making nav mesh agent dynamically. But it showing this warning as it create

> Failed to create agent because it is not close enough to the NavMesh
>   UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate(GenericIndividual)
>   STB.PACS.GenericIndividualPoll:.ctor(GenericIndividual) (at
>   Assets/STB/PACS/Source/System/GenericIndividualPoll.cs:48)
>   STB.PACS.IndividualPath:Start() (at Assets/STB/PACS/Source/Sys

Below are some images:

[image]

[image]